# Rest request method PUT JSON array (string) C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, rest, request

My problem is:

I have a JSON format string array:

```
 [
  {
    "Calle": "San pedro te asalto",
    "CodigoPostal": "",
    "Colonia": "",
    "CorreoElectronicoReceptor": "luis.garcia@ixpan.com.mx",
    "DelegacionMunicipio": "",
    "Estado": "Distrito Federal",
    "FechaRegistro": "/Date(-62135596800000+0000)/",
    "FechaUltimaModificacion": "/Date(-62135596800000+0000)/",
    "IdCliente": 44170,
    "IdClienteEmpresa": null,
    "IdEmpresa": 0,
    "IdEstadoCliente": 1,
    "IdMetodoPago": 0,
    "IdUsuario": 0,
    "Localidad": null,
    "NombreContacto": "",
    "NombreRazonSocial": "",
    "NumCuenta": null,
    "NumExterior": null,
    "NumInterior": null,
    "Pais": "México",
    "RFCReceptor": "XAXA010101XA0",
    "Referencia": null,
    "TelFijoClaveInternacional": "",
    "TelFijoExt": "",
    "TelFijoReceptor": "",
    "TelMoviReceptor": "",
    "TelMovilClaveInternacional": ""
  },
  {
    "Calle": "Terricola oriental",
    "CodigoPostal": "",
    "Colonia": "",
    "CorreoElectronicoReceptor": "gabo.luna@ixpan.com.mx",
    "DelegacionMunicipio": "",
    "Estado": "Distrito Federal",
    "FechaRegistro": "/Date(-62135596800000+0000)/",
    "FechaUltimaModificacion": "/Date(-62135596800000+0000)/",
    "IdCliente": 44171,
    "IdClienteEmpresa": null,
    "IdEmpresa": 0,
    "IdEstadoCliente": 1,
    "IdMetodoPago": 0,
    "IdUsuario": 0,
    "Localidad": null,
    "NombreContacto": "",
    "NombreRazonSocial": "",
    "NumCuenta": null,
    "NumExterior": null,
    "NumInterior": null,
    "Pais": "México",
    "RFCReceptor": "LUPC910202HDF",
    "Referencia": null,
    "TelFijoClaveInternacional": "",
    "TelFijoExt": "",
    "TelFijoReceptor": "",
    "TelMoviReceptor": "",
    "TelMovilClaveInternacional": ""
  },
  {
    "Calle": "Via lactea rectal",
    "CodigoPostal": "",
    "Colonia": "",
    "CorreoElectronicoReceptor": "arturo.madrid@iofacturo.mx",
    "DelegacionMunicipio": "",
    "Estado": "Distrito Federal",
    "FechaRegistro": "/Date(-62135596800000+0000)/",
    "FechaUltimaModificacion": "/Date(-62135596800000+0000)/",
    "IdCliente": 44172,
    "IdClienteEmpresa": null,
    "IdEmpresa": 0,
    "IdEstadoCliente": 1,
    "IdMetodoPago": 0,
    "IdUsuario": 0,
    "Localidad": null,
    "NombreContacto": "",
    "NombreRazonSocial": "",
    "NumCuenta": null,
    "NumExterior": null,
    "NumInterior": null,
    "Pais": "México",
    "RFCReceptor": "CMS941215JF7",
    "Referencia": null,
    "TelFijoClaveInternacional": "",
    "TelFijoExt": "",
    "TelFijoReceptor": "",
    "TelMoviReceptor": "",
    "TelMovilClaveInternacional": ""
  }
]
```

My contract is:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT",
            UriTemplate = "/updatedProduct?Token={Token}&Entity={Entity}",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped
            )]
        ResPostList updatedProduct(String Token, String Entidad);
```

...localhost/myService/updatedProduct?Token=MyToken&Entity=MyJSONArrayInString

My problem is when I send a JSON array, if sending JSON plane, my method works well, that's what I need to add?

Comment: Its not entirely clear what the problem is. Do you mind rephrasing your question? One thing that struck me as odd is the way you are sending the whole array in a query string parameter instead of in the body of the request. If you are trying to write a RESTful service, the recommendation is to send the payload in the body of the request.

Comment: Sure! I would like to send a JSON as a parameter that contains one or more elements of an entity.

When I try to send the parameter with 3 elements of the entity doesn't work because it doesn't enter in the method, I've tried with only ONE element of the entity and that's the only way that it works.

I'm using http://www.soapui.org/  like IDE to test the REST service

Thanks

Comment: Do you see an error on the client side (SOAP UI or browser from which you are making the request)? Also, if you are using IIS, you should be careful about how much data you send in the query string - IIS has a limit (which you can potentially increase but i wouldn't recommend doing that but instead look at sending the payload via http request body).

Comment: Thank You! The problem was the size of string, not the array JSON. Was resolved by passing the parameters of the request body . So as you mentioned. Thank You!